# Getting the number of times an element appeared in an array and render in reactjs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I am building a `react native` app with `node.js` and `mysql`. It is a delivery app and I would like to get each user's purchased items and number of times each item the user has purchased each of these items. I really don't know the best way to go about this but I decided to have it this way.
Here is a sample data of users:

```
const users = [
    {
       id: 1,    
        purchasedItems: ['Noodles with Chicken and Coca Cola', "Noodles with Chicken and Coca Cola", "Jollof rice with chicken and plantain" , "Jollof rice with chicken and plantain", "Jollof rice with chicken and plantain",
            "Fried Rice with Chicken", "Fried Snail with chilled Coca Cola"  
        ],
       
    },

    {
        id: 2,
        purchasedItems: ['Noodles with Chicken and Coca Cola', "Noodles with Chicken and Coca Cola", "Jollof rice with chicken and plantain", "Jollof rice with chicken and plantain",
            "Fried Snail with chilled Coca Cola",  "Fried Snail with chilled Coca Cola",  "Fried Snail with chilled Coca Cola"  
        ],
    },
]
```

Since in the `purchasedItem` object array, some items appeared more than once. The idea is that once a user makes a successful purchase, I would push the name of that item into his `purchasedItems` list. This means there can be multiple instances. To render only unique values in my react Native app, I used this code:

```
const arrayData = statDetails.purchasedItems;//statsDetails is the individual user. I used `flatList`
let uniqueArray = []
for(const num of arrayData){
    if(!uniqueArray.includes(num)){
        uniqueArray.push(num)
    }
}
```

I needed to get the number of times each of these elements appeared in each user's `purchasedItem` list. I used this code:

```
let newValye = []

const counts = {};

for (const num of arrayData) {
  counts[num] = counts[num] ? counts[num] + 1 : 1;
    newValye.push(counts[num])
  
}
```

The result is a single object which I couldn't use in reactnative. I needed to create an array of multiple objects to render these values in react native. I used this code:

```
const countArry = []

Object.values(counts).forEach(val => countArry.push({item: val}));
```

I simply used `flatList` to render the `countArray` which actually works as I wanted but the code looks too long. Is there a better way to handle this? Any idea is appreciated.

I listed the codes I have used so far

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to have your `purchasedItems` array contain objects in this format:

```
const users = [
    {
        id: 1,
        purchasedItems: [
            {
                item: 'Noodles with Chicken and Coca Cola',
                quantity: 2
            },  
        ],
    },
]
```

This way you can get unique purchased items and get the purchased quantity easily.

Example for unique items of the first user:

```
const items = users[0].purchasedItems.map((e) => e.item)
```

Test:

```js
const users = [
    {
        id: 1,
        purchasedItems: [
            {
                item: 'Noodles with Chicken and Coca Cola',
                quantity: 2
            },
            {
                item: 'Fried Snail with chilled Coca Cola',
                quantity: 1
            }, 
        ],
    },
]

const items = users[0].purchasedItems.map((e) => e.item)

console.log(items)
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. What if user buys same item more than once, we are to create multiple instances of the same product item which makes no sense. How can someone solve that?

Comment: Because we dont know what users will buy, we can only push what they bought inside the purchasedItem array. If we make it an object, how do we update the object instance